# Rails4, MySql, mysql2 encoding issue

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a project where Rails 4, MySql 5.1, gem mysql2 are used.

This stack worked fine until today. I've added two fields in a table (added corresponding migration) and if I save data to the table, the data in this field will look ugly, like -%D0%9D%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8

Here is Rails log:

This is the data from a request. All looks fine, 'name' and 'comment' are in Russian.

```
Parameters: {"{\"user_id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"АБВ\",\"email\":\"mike@outofcloud.ru\",\"answer\":\"5\",\"comment\":\"цувцув\"}"=>nil}
```

But in the SQL statement the 'name' parameter changed:

```
SQL (23.3ms) INSERT INTO "feedbacks" ("answer", "code", "comment", "created_at", "email", "name", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8) RETURNING "id" [["answer", 5], ["code", 1], ["comment", "цувцув"], ["created_at", "2015-05-13 08:54:22.047321"], ["email", "example@example.ru"], ["name", **"%D0%90%D0%91%D0%92"**], ["updated_at", "2015-05-13 08:54:22.047321"], ["user_id", "1"]]
```

'comment' field was added before my migrations, it works as expected. It look great in the DB and in the app.
'name' field have been added recently and its doesn't work as expected.

Can someone help with the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The string that you're showing is the result of using `URI.encode` on `"АБВ"` - see:

```
[4] pry(main)> URI.encode "АБВ"
=> "%D0%90%D0%91%D0%92"
```

Rails doesn't do this by itself. You must have some code somewhere else (or, hopefully not, a gem) that's performing that transformation.

If you don't know where that is then please add the code from your controllers showing any `before_action` methods, or other transformations. Also the code from your model if you're doing anything `before_save` or any custom attribute setters, eg. `def name=`